# Import Angular Material components in an Ionic Project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material, ionic4

I'm trying to use Angular Material in an Ionic 4 Project. I have already installed all the dependencies needed through NPM. In order to get a more clean and maintainable code, I've created a separate `ngModule` which imports all the components that I need in my application,following the Angular Material Docs(the Getting Start part).
Then, I've imported it in the page module where I want to use it.
However, when I want to start the material component, It looks like the import is not being used, so I can't use the component.

I've tried to import the material components module directly in the app.module.ts file, with the same results.I could just import each component that I want to use directly,instead of the module with all of them, but I really want to know why this approach is not working, and if is there anything I'm not doing correctly.

So this is how my custom module looks:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ]
})
export class AppMaterialModule { }
```

And this how I'm trying to import it where I want to use it:

```ts
import { AppMaterialModule} from '../../app-material.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    AppMaterialModule,
    ....
  ]
 ...
```

I expect to be able to use all the material components imported in `AppMaterialModule` just including this module where I'm using then, but somehow this approach is not working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo
If I try to use for example a paginator component:
`'mat-paginator' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-paginator' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-paginator' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.`

Comment: for angular 9+ check this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295166/how-to-import-all-angular-material-modules-in-angular-9

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup which works for Ionic4.

Like you I have a custom module called `MaterialModule`. (Trim this down to the Modules you need).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule],
  exports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule],
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

which I import in my `app.module.ts` file:

```
...
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
...


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    ...
    MaterialModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I was using the same structure but it doesnt seem to work. However,If you are telling me that it's working for you in Ionic 4 there's definitely something I am missing. So i'll keep looking around it. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I had to import each module separately

```js
// MatTableModule
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
// MatButtonModule
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
...
```