# How to import all Angular Material modules in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9, angular-module, angular-cli-v9

I want to import all angular material modules and use into overall angular project templates.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

We can create a new module and import all material modules in the new module and use into our templates.

Please use this command and run into Angular CLI:
`ng g m material --module=app`

`--module=app` - this command will automatically import newly created **MaterialModule** module and add into AppModule imports[] array.

Now open **MaterialModule** file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
// Material Form Controls
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
// Material Navigation
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
// Material Layout
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
// Material Buttons & Indicators
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
// Material Popups & Modals
import { MatBottomSheetModule } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
// Material Data tables
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

DONE!!!

Now we can use material components in our templates.

Comment: Weird that this is the best option we have.

Comment: You do not need to put all these separate modules in the imports array nowadays

Comment: I think you can remove both `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';` and also the whole `imports: [...]`.

Comment: But make sure to comment out all modules in first place and only uncomment those that you actually need.

Answer (score 22):

create new module `material-module.ts` under `app` and add this

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {ClipboardModule} from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {CdkTreeModule} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';
import {MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {OverlayModule} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    A11yModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    OverlayModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule,
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

now import in in `app-module.ts`

```
import {MaterialModule} from './material-module'
```

You can find this in any angular material  stackblitz

ex:  https://stackblitz.com/angular/klapkamavve?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 11):

Never import all the material modules as mentioned above. Its better to import only whatever you use or require for your development because **it will increase your bundle size and will make your application slow in the production environment.**

Comment: However, what if most of those components is usually needed. So it's easier to import everything and remove a few elements than to add one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Not to advance an old thread, but struggling with this in 2023 and not knowing if its a new version difference or not, but here's what fixed my issue.

MAKE SURE YOUR app.module.ts is declaring all of your components, if you want them to inherit imports from app.module, it has to be aware of them (declarables), note the declarations section, if your component isnt present here it can't inherit from app.module imports

[image: pay attention to declarations array]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097

Please see this link. Its important not share code in images.

Answer (score -3):

IVY is enabled by default so tree shaking will make sure all the unreferenced modules will be shaken

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question. Please edit your answer so it will be relevant to he OP question