# Importing Angular Component Lib Module in every NgModule

Tags: angular, performance, components, ng-modules

In a project, we are using our clients web components that were converted to Angular components. Right now every time we need to use a single component we have to import the entire module containing every component.

Does Angular optimize imports or will this cause the application to get bloated? Whats the best way of handling this?

I couldnt word this properly to find answers googling...

Comment: you can import in the app module and then export it from there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295166/how-to-import-all-angular-material-modules-in-angular-9

Comment: "Does Angular optimize imports or will this cause the application to get bloated?"
I'd like to have this answerded!

Comment: If it's using Ivy (version 9+) then it's optimized, check "tree shaking" term in angular