# How to declare an Array of angular Material modules?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295166/how-to-import-all-angular-material-modules-in-angular-9), and various blog posts, recommend a separate module to import your Material Modules and immediately export them, then import that module into your `app.module.ts` to prevent polluting the app module.

It seems to me that if imports are always identical to exports then I would prefer to declare them only once. So, I use

```
const materialModules = [
  MatButtonModule, MatIconModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatDatepickerModule,
  MatCheckboxModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: materialModules,
  exports: materialModules,
})

export class MaterialModule{}
```

This works fine, but I would like to give a type to `materialModules`. What should it be?

Comment: Material modules don't implement a common interface, so I guess the type can only be `any[]`

Comment: Thanks (+1). it won't help the IDE, which is what I was looking for by adding a type. But you have helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, these modules are passed to imports array and since imports take the below type:

> `(any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>)`

We don't have any other options other than the above type.

So you can do

```
 const materialModules : (any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>) = [
  MatButtonModule, MatIconModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatDatepickerModule,
  MatCheckboxModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule,
];
```

But to me it doesn't add much benefit.

Comment: "`But to me it doesn't add much benefit.`". Nope, it doesn't. I just like to explicitly declare types where I can, even when not needed. Sometimes that can help the IDE. You have certainly helped me. Thanks, upvote & accepted answer