# For angular material, in which module is the md-content directive and how do I import it?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

In the context of an angular material typescript app, I am trying to use the md-content directive listed in the angular material documentation here:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/content
And here:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdContent

But I cannot figure out how to import the right angular material module which contains this directive.

I tried searching all the available modules here:
https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/api

I tried importing all the available module as listed here:
[How to import all Angular Material modules in Angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295166/how-to-import-all-angular-material-modules-in-angular-9)

None of the above has worked, i still get the basic error:  "error NG8001: 'md-content' is not a known element."

Please note that I am able to import and use all the other modules just fine. I am just not able to find this specific one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using **Angularjs**? or **Angular** (from Angular2 to Angular12,13,...).

I say this because the doc you show is old, for angularjs, not for Angular which has its own in:
**material.angular.io**

A new componet that fits with yours (**mdcontent**), could be this one, **< mat-expansion-panel >** :

https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview